# Using AWS Lambda to read and print a CSV file as Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, dataframe, aws-lambda

I have working python scripts that read information from a CSV file into a pandas dataframe, then display the pandas dataframe in my Python console window. I would like to incorporate this script into a website using AWS Lambda, where the dataframe is printed on screen in AWS versus my Python console. I am new to coding and do not have much experience with AWS or Lambda. Could someone please refer me to the resources needed to do this?

I know I will need to somehow store the file in the cloud, most likely using S3. Then I need to have a lambda script to read the file from S3. Are there any resources you all have used to learn this?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use the AWS Pandas library which can help you to read the file from S3 into dataframe.

https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/003%20-%20Amazon%20S3.html

Another thing is Lambda's execution time of maximum 15 minutes. If your files are huge then it might be an issue.
Also to store the files to S3 which are uploaded you would need to use presigned S3 URL . There are still some moving parts about how the UI and lambda will sync if the users uploads file to S3 given API gateway has a 5 Mb limitation